# jQuery remove text from HTML tag

Tags: jquery, html, regex, join, split

I am having problems using a regex to extract the `<h1></h1>` tag.

I have the variable:

```
var t = '<h1>Some cool text in this tag</h1>';
```

and I want to make it like this:

```
<h1><span>Some</span> <span>cool</span> <span>text</span> <span>in</span> <span>this</span> <span>tag</span></h1>
```

My code looks like this:

```
var t = '<h1>Some cool text in this tag</h1>';
var reg = /<(.|\n)*?>/ig;  // this is regex for HTML tags
var temp = '';
var s = $(t).text();

temp = '<span>'+ s.split(' ').join('</span> <span>')+'</span>';

$('#output').append(temp);
```

It should work with every possible HTML tags, even when the var has a string like:

```
var t = '<strong>Strong text</strong> with some <em>emphasis</em>';
```

"working" example here: http://codepen.io/halol/pen/DKeIu

Comment: what is the expected o/p of `'<strong>Strong text</strong> with some <em>emphasis</em>'`

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having, from the description given it seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: I want to separate the tags and the text.
Then join them, but every word with span tag

Comment: When I run your script above on the second example, I get this: "<span>Strong</span> <span>text</span> <span>with</span> <span>some</span> <span>emphasis</span>". Is that not correct? Can you show what the end result should look like?  (your codepen sample is different, and returns a different result than what you listed above, which seems to work) ?

Comment: <span><strong>Strong</strong></span> <span>text</span> <span>with</span> <span>some</span> <span><em>emphasis</em></span>

Every word sholud be in <span> tag, but when is an example like this: <h1>Some text</h1> sholud be: <h1><span>Some</span> <span>text</span></h1> or like example output above

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find matching html tags with regex is rough, since they may be nested.  In any case, would something like this do what you need?  Or at least help get you in the right direction?

```
$('#target').children().each(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<span></span>');
  t = $(this).text();
  t = '<span>'+ t.split(' ').join('</span> <span>')+'</span>';
  $(this).html(t);
})
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s_Oaten/85W3B/

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var t = '<h1>Some cool text in this tag</h1>';
var text = t.split(' ');

for( var i = 1, len = text.length; i < len; i=i+2 ) {
    text[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
alert(text.join(' '))
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UReCb/